# Is union all going to work on this?

Tags: mysql, sql, html-table

I have two tables, income and expenditure, tried using union all, but the problem is the expense column is getting displayed in income and therefore affecting the balance. Any idea on where I am going wrong?

```
<?php
include "connection.php" ;

$result = mysql_query("select date, particulars, trntype, subincome, income, remarks,1 AS dummy from income UNION ALL select date, particulars, trntype, subexpense, expense,remarks, 2 AS dummy from expenditure ORDER BY `date` ASC, dummy ASC");
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Particulars</th>
<th>Transaction Type</th>
<th>Sub Expense</th>
<th>Expense</th>
<th>Sub Income</th>
<th>Income</th>
<th>Cash In Hand</th>
<th>Remarks</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
   echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['particulars'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['trntype'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['subexpense'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['expense'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['subincome'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['income'] . "</td>";
  $cashinhand = $cashinhand + $row['income'] + $row['income'] - $row['subexpense'] - $row['expense'] ;
    echo "<td>" . $cashinhand . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['remarks'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";

?>
```

Here, instead of displaying the subexpense and expense, in Sub Expense and Expense column, they are printed into Sub Income and Income column. Naturally, the Balance is getting added instead of reduced.

Answer (score 1):

What happens in your query is that you mix expense and income in the same columns (cols 3 and 4).

Try adding `null` on columns you don't need for each query :

```
SELECT date,
       particulars,
       trntype,
       NULL as subexpense,
       NULL as expense,
       subincome,
       income,
       remarks,
       1 AS dummy
FROM   income
UNION ALL
SELECT date,
       particulars,
       trntype,
       subexpense,
       expense,
       NULL as subincome,
       NULL as income,
       remarks,
       2 AS dummy
FROM   expenditure
ORDER  BY `date` ASC,
          dummy ASC
```

This way, each subquery is formatted the same way as the expected HTML output, with a different column for each value type.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a pseudo column in each query to keep the separated for the union.

```
select date, particulars, trntype, subincome, income, 
  null as expence, remarks,1 AS dummy 
from income 
UNION ALL 
select date, particulars, trntype, subexpense, null as income, 
    expense, remarks, 2 AS dummy from expenditure ORDER BY `date` ASC, dummy ASC
```